# How do you use Fourier transforms to perform a deconvolution

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing, convolution

I've been trying to teach myself about deconvolution through Fourier transforms, but I seem to be missing something simple, as my results are garbage.

I start by defining a test function and a window which I will convolve with it

```
Window[width_, x_] = UnitStep[x + width/2] UnitStep[width/2 - x];
Test[x_] = UnitStep[x] UnitStep[count - x] Sin[0.1 x]^2;
```

I then sample the convolution across a set of data points

```
count=100;

MakeData[width_] = 
  Simplify[Table[
    Integrate[Window[width, x - i] Test[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
     Assumptions -> {count > width > 0}], {i, 0, count}]];

tempData = MakeData[20];
```

I make a similar list for my sample window

```
tempWindow = Table[Window[20, x], {x, -count/2, count/2}];
```

I use the convolution theorem to deconvolve my window from my data

```
deconvolved = InverseFourier[Fourier[tempData]/Fourier[tempWindow]];
```

I was expect that this will return the original function

```
expected = Table[Test[x], {x, 0, count}];
```

However, the results are completely different.

[image: Graph of Results]

There's obviously something I'm doing wrong in my convolution or deconvolution, but I don't see what it is.

Comment: For starters, you're generating the data by sampling the theoretical result of the convolution but trying to deconvolve some other sampled window... Deconvolutions (noisy) are generally unstable. See [this message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=6114407#6114407) of mine for an example demonstrating the convolution theorem (`a` and `b` are random vectors).

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is related to MMA. 
Anyway, when your window has zeros, as usually happens, the result is not unique and unstable. You can try making your smallest values of `Fourier@tempData` be really zero, and add some small constant value to the denominator to get zero out of those 0/0. Furthermore, your convolution formula only works because it is even. Otherwise it should say `Window[width, x - i]`. Furthermore, given that you didn't rotate your window samples, and sampled from `-count/2`, your `expected` should be rotated right `count/2`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While it's tempting to attribute the errors you're observing to floating-point errors due to zeros in the DFT of the window, this is actually not the case here:

```
Window[width_, x_] := UnitStep[x + width/2] UnitStep[width/2 - x];
Test[x_] := UnitStep[x] UnitStep[count - x] Sin[1/10 x]^2;
tempWindow = Table[Window[20, x], {x, -count/2, count/2}];
{Min[Abs[Fourier[tempWindow]]],Max[Abs[Fourier[tempWindow]]]}

(*Out: {0.00455694, 2.08958}*)
```

Instead, the primary issue is a misuse of the convolution theorem. The inverse DFT of the product of the DFT's of the samples of two functions is NOT the samples of the convolution of the two functions; rather, it is the cyclic convolution of the samples of the two functions, which is an important distinction.

Your code samples the convolution of the two functions (I modified it to be a bit cleaner):

```
count = 100;
expr=Integrate[Window[width, x - i] Test[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];
tempData = N@Table[expr/.width->20,{i,0,count}];
```

It then samples the window function, and then attempts to deconvolve the sampled window from the samples of the convolution of the two functions:

```
deconvolved = Abs[InverseFourier[Fourier[tempData]/Fourier[tempWindow]]];
```

The result looks like nonsense because `tempData` is not actually a cyclic convolution of `tempWindow` with the samples of `Test`, so you have no reason to expect that the cyclic deconvolution of `tempData` with the samples of `Window` will give you the samples of `Test`. It's a bit of a subtle error, but it's actually very important.

For reference, to demonstrate the cyclic convolution and deconvolution, try this:

```
tempTest = Table[Test[x], {x, -count/2, count/2}];
tempConv = Re@InverseFourier[Fourier[tempTest] Fourier[RotateLeft[tempWindow,count/2]]];
tempDeconv = Re@InverseFourier[Fourier[tempConv]/Fourier[RotateLeft[tempWindow, count/2]]];
ListPlot[tempTest]
ListPlot[tempConv]
ListPlot[tempDeconv - tempTest]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What a nice answer & explanation. +1

Comment: That was an incredibly clear explanation.  Thank you.